# Laravel 8 Public CSS doesn't affect the webpage

Tags: css, laravel

I have my css file in public (public/css/custom.css) then I put this code inside my app.blade.php

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

everything works fine. Next day, I wanted to edit the custom.css file, but the style on the website didn't change, even when I deleted the custom.css file it didn't affect the style of the page like it did still exist in the folder, but when I delete that code, it didn't recognize the custom.css like it should. How did this happend? how can I fix this? I'm very confuse with this situation.

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear the cache on your browser?  I think you got the browser cache the css from your site.

I recommend you use Laravel mix to compile the assets :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix